# jQuery Ajax POST Failing

Tags: ajax, jquery, twitter

I can't get my AJAX request to complete successfully. It's for the bearere token on Twitter's API. I have done successfully in a HTTP request client as shown below:

[image: success]

But I can't replicate this in code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token',
        headers: {
            'Authorization':'Basic ' + base64EncodedBearerTokenCredentials,
        },
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        data: {
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        },
        success: function(response){
        },
    });
```

I'm getting a 405, but because I have the Authorization header in I can't see the response in Firebug.

What is it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try dropping `contentType`.

Comment: thanks but still no luck

Comment: Can you compare the request properties in that tool you're using to the jQuery call and see any differences?

Comment: Nope, unsure how. I think it might be the data attribute? Twitter ask for 'grant_type=client_credentials' which i've tried as a raw string without luck too

Comment: Cross domain ajax probably tripping you up. Put the post on your own separate page in whatever language you are using (PHP cURL for example) and send the ajax request to your page on your domain.

Comment: I'm writing a Javascript app :/ . Could make a PHP page I guess... Thanks for the suggestion.